# Java - If condition to check if an Integer array-list contains element which is greater than particular value

Tags: java, collections, break

I have updated my code. I have 3 arraylists and based on the condition I want to update values. I am using for each loop to iterate but now I am doing something wrong with the break it is not resetting/picking up next value for type and len. It is only resetting name.

```
 List <String> columnNameList = new ArrayList <String>();
    List <String> columnTypeList = new ArrayList <String>();
    List <Integer> columnLengthList = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    String result = "";

                    columnNameList.add("Id");
                    columnNameList.add("Name");
                    columnNameList.add("Address");

                    columnTypeList.add("char");
                    columnTypeList.add("varchar");
                    columnTypeList.add("varchar");


                    columnLengthList.add(18);
                    columnLengthList.add(50);
                    columnLengthList.add(10000);




                    outermostloop: for (String name : columnNameList )
                    { 
                        outerloop:  for (String type : columnTypeList)
                        {
                            loop: for (int len : columnLengthList)
                            {

                                if(len > 0 && (!type.equalsIgnoreCase("int") && !type.equalsIgnoreCase("datetime") && !type.equalsIgnoreCase("datetime2")))
                                        {

                                    if(len > 8000 && !(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Id")) && (type.equalsIgnoreCase("varchar")))
                                    {
                                        result =  name + type + "(max) ";
                                        System.out.println("if len > 8000 && name not id and type is varchar " + result);  
                                        // O/P expected : Address  varchar(max)
                                    }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        String finalres = name + type + "("+ len +") ";
                                        System.out.println("No conversion " + finalres);    
                                        /* O/P expected : Id char(18)
                                                         Name varchar(50) 
                                         */

                                    }

                                        }

                                break outerloop;


                            } 

                        }  

                    }

But what I am getting with above logic :
No conversion Id char (18) 
No conversion Name char (18) 
No conversion Address char (18)
```

Comment: Do you have any question? or just felt like sharing with us?

Answer (score 4):

You have to iterate over the elements of the `List` until you find an element larger than 8000.

With `Stream`s you can write it with:

```
if (columnLengthList.stream().anyMatch(i -> i > 8000)) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: either that, or just sort the List, and compare it to the largest

Comment: @Stultuske sorting is more expansive than finding the first element larger than X (O(nlogn) vs. O(n)).

Comment: In case someone is still sitting on a very old Java version, the good old `Collections.max(columnLengthList) > 8000` runs in linear time too (though it’s not short-circuiting).

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<Integer> ar1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ar1.add(1);
    ar1.add(2);
    ar1.add(3);
    ar1.add(4);
    ar1.add(5);

    int particular_value = 3;

    for (int i : ar1) {
        if (i > particular_value)
            System.out.println("Value " + i + " is greater than " + particular_value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the list. Either using streams or an extended for loop or a general for loop.
For ex:

```
List <Integer> columnLengthList = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        columnLengthList.add(8001);
        columnLengthList.add(7000);

        for (Integer eachElement: columnLengthList) {
            if (eachElement > 8000) {
                // run these 
            } else {
                // run these
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will do the job. But as practice don't use subtype to create list. Best way is `List <Integer> columnLengthList = new ArrayList <>();`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I just copied it from the question and it went unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks all for the prompt reply! But now I am having some other issues with the same logic. I am updating my post with updated code. Can you please look into it.